# Programatically fill inputs and submit AngularJS form after App is opened with URI Intent

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, android-intent

I have an Ionic 1 + AngularJS app, with cordova, that runs on Android.

I'm using this cordova plugin (https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent) to get intent.extras when I open it with another App.

My question is: how can I fill the inputs and make the ng-submit programatically after the app is opened by another app?

If I fill the inputs with javascript, when I manually submit the form, the values that are submitted are the old ones.

```
window.plugins.intentShim.onIntent(function (intent) {
    console.log('Received Intent: ' + JSON.stringify(intent.extras));
    if (intent.extras){
        document.getElementById('field1').value = intent.extras.field1||"";
        document.getElementById('field2').value = intent.extras.field2||"";
        document.getElementById('field3').value = intent.extras.field3||"A";
        //apply the values on Angular context and submit
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I 'solve' my problem using document.getElementById('field1').value inside angular controller to get the input content instead of using angular ng-model value.